# Can I avoid using isset() to handle "undefined variable" errors?

Tags: php, wamp, undefined, isset

I manage a very old PHP/MySQL site that make extensive use of the following syntax to check if a variable is set :

```
if($var){ /* do something  */ }
```

I know that the proper way way to handle this to use the **isset()** fonction ... **But I can't**. The online version works fine (on an old gentoo server), the local version works fine on a very old Windows XP computer with wamp 2.0 (I know) and this syntax is used EVERYWHERE in the code.

I would like to copy my local version on a more recent/faster computer. I installed the same wamp version that on the old Windows XP computer but I get undreds of "*Notice : undefined variable / index ...*" errors. I suspect that something can be done in the wamp *PHP settings* but I have no idea where to look or what to do. I works on the old computer and online : there must be a way to make it work on a more recent computer.

EDIT: I would like to "tell" PHP to handle "unedefined" variable as "false" variables (that's how it works on the XP server). Turning errors off won't do the trick. I need the `if($var){...` to function as `if(isset($var)){...`.

On both servers (XP en new PC) the version are as follows :

- Wamp : 2.0i
- Apache : 2.2.11
- PHP : 5.3.0
- MySQL : 5.1.36

Any help is appreciated & thanks in advance.
This is my first question on this fine site : apologies if I did anything wrong.

EDIT 2 : a SOLUTION was found with thanks to @Boratzan (see balow). I copied both `php.ini` (1 from the **Apache folder** and 1 from the **PHP folder**) from the old computer to the new one with some minor path edit to take into account the fact that both wamp servers were not installed in the same path.

EDIT 3 : After further investigation, it appears that @Boratzan was right from the beginning. the solution was to change the value of `error_reporting` to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` in the **php.ini** file located in the **apache/ApacheX.X.XX/bin/** directory. This is a sloppy solution but it

Comment: I suggest you just try it and see what happens :)

Comment: You *can* but you don't *want* to. Legacy code is a pain but if you want to avoid these errors you have to go through and check to see if they are set.

Comment: share your code...?

Comment: You are probably looking for `error_reporting` setting, but as the others mention, it is better to fix Your code.

Comment: The code does NOT work on the new PC. I would love to fix this awful syntax with "isset" (it burns my eyes !) but the site is too big to correct every file. This really is site-wide issue, not a problem I encountered on one specific script.

Comment: How many .php and .html files have the website?

Comment: There are several hundreds (some are useless but it is always hard to tell when previous guy left a mess)

Comment: If you can migrate your server and dev environment to PHP 7.0+, you can use the [`null coalesce operator(??)`](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/isset_ternary).

Also, PHP 5.3 is no more updated, and may have many security and performance issues.

Comment: Can you please show the complete text of one of those notices? So including error code/number and error message (no need to show the file path from it).

Comment: here are the 1st 3 messages (site name edited) : `Notice: Undefined index: qtePlus in D:\wamp\www\...\inc\panier.inc.php on line 3` • `Notice: Undefined index: qteMoins in D:\wamp\www\...\inc\panier.inc.php on line 8` • `Notice: Undefined index: suppProd in D:\wamp\www\...\inc\panier.inc.php on line 13`

Comment: The things are getting complicated when you "_need the if($var){... to function as if(isset($var)){..._". If $var is an array and you check it with `isset()` does not mean that you check it for `empty()` too. But the `if ($var)` does both. I hope you understand me :-)

Comment: I understand what you mean and I takle this into account when I write code but I need to run some bad code that I did not write. Anyway I solved the problem with the help of Boratzan (see 2nd Answer) ... or he solved it for me. =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wouldn't recommend it, but if you want to have it running without the errors shown, disable [error_reporting](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) with the following piece of code:

```
ini_set('error_reporting', 0);
```

OR

```
error_reporting(0);
```

Again, it's better to fix your code, but if you proceed with this anyways, you could also try to setting the value to `E_ALL & ~E_NOTICE` which only hides the *NOTICE* warnings

To answer your question why it does work on the previous WAMP installation and online, it's probably because those have `display_errors` configured to `off` (mainly done in production environments, not recommend while developing)

---

Since none of the above helped solving your problem, you could compare both .ini files from the installations or simply copy the working one into the new one (assuming they both run the same version).

WAMP has two php.ini files, one in the PHP folder and one in the Apache folder, make sure you copy them both (or at least the one located in the Apache folder).

Comment: Tanks for the suggestion : It hides the errors but the problem remains. What I need is for PHP to understand "unedefined" as "false" ...  that is the way the old server handles it. This is a  mistery. Thank you anyway =)

Comment: Then there is something else which is causing the issue, is the code even running properly beside the if statements? Perhaps you need to enable `short_open_tag `

Comment: all files are usin `<?php ?>` ... so I don't think that `short_open_tag` would change anything. But thanks anyway. =)

Comment: Well then I can think of only one thing, either compare both .ini files from the installations or just copy the .ini files from the working installation to the new one (assuming they both run the same version)

Comment: I already copied the php.ini file from the XP computer to the new one ... it did not work. Is that the ini file you were thinking of ?

Comment: There are two php.ini files, did you replace the file in the Apache folder?

Comment: IT WORKED !! I copied also copied the php.ini file from the Apache folder ... and it works ! thank you very much !!!

Comment: @Boratzan Great work! ;-) It would be great if you would pass the solution from the comments into your answer, so that other users benefit from it. So, +1 from me.

Comment: @Boratzan Perfect. One more thing: On php.net there is presented  another great way to filter out certain errors/warnings/notices etc, based on their error codes/messages: [Example #1 Error handling with set_error_handler()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php#refsect1-function.set-error-handler-examples). For example, in the `case E_NOTICE:` of `myErrorHandler()` you can check if the substring `Undefined index` exists in the error message. If yes, just `return true;`. Then only the `Undefined index` notices will be surpressed from the whole list.

Comment: @Boratzan P.S: Only `myErrorHandler()` is relevant from the example.

Comment: I edited my question with the solution ...  and due credit ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `@` to suppress a specific error: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php

Or banally turn off all errors.